# GUI tower defense: path and enemies

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, game

Working on creating new tower defense in JS. May be port to React.

How to improve? Only made enemies and path so far.

In below demo, path is white background and enemy is red circles and green squares. Enemy may have different type: triangle or different speed.

```js
"use strict";

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/15313435
function assert(condition, message) {
  if (!condition) {
    throw new Error(message || "Assertion failed");
  }
}

// Interface check. All must have sprite function
function isCompleteEnemyType(obj) {
  assert(typeof(obj.getSprite) == "function");
}

var c = document.getElementById("main-canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

class EnemySquare {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  static getSprite() {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = 100;
    canvas.height = 100;

    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.rect(10, 10, 80, 80);
    context.fillStyle = "#00FF0050";
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();

    return canvas;
  }

  move() {
    this.y -= 1;

    // add some sway
    this.x += Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 3);
  }

  get pos() {
    return [this.x, this.y];
  }
}

class EnemyCircle {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  static getSprite() {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = 100;
    canvas.height = 100;

    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.arc(50, 50, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    context.fillStyle = "#FF000050";
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();

    return canvas;
  }

  move() {
    this.y -= 1;

    // add some sway
    this.x += Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 3);
  }

  get pos() {
    return [this.x, this.y];
  }
}

isCompleteEnemyType(EnemyCircle);
isCompleteEnemyType(EnemySquare);

// Enemies would be loaded in from level1.json
var enemies = new Set([
  new EnemyCircle(10, 350),
  new EnemySquare(25, 350),
  new EnemySquare(50, 400),
  new EnemySquare(50, 400), // overlap is allowed
]);

function nextFrame(frameNum = 0) {
  if (frameNum > 400) {
    return;
  }

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

  enemies.forEach((enemy) => {
    var sprite = enemy.constructor.getSprite();
    var [x, y] = enemy.pos;

    ctx.drawImage(sprite, x, y);

    enemy.move();
  });

  setTimeout(() => nextFrame(frameNum + 1), 50);
}

nextFrame();
```

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  /* image-rendering: pixelated; */
  object-fit: contain;
  height: 80%;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

.flex-container {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <canvas id="main-canvas" width="200" height="400" style="border:1px solid #000000;" />
</div>
```

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @pacmaninbw only change after first answer is auto format code and does not invalidate existing answer

Comment: Which is why I did not roll back the edits.

Answer (score 3):

- I suggest you use `requestAnimationFrame` for your game loop instead of `setTimeout` to make the animation smooth and make sure you only use resources necessary for your calculations. At the same time, it's then better to measure "delta" between calls and calculate move distance and other game logic accordingly based on this value. Overall, I suggest to look up "game loop" pattern and implement it a bit more explicitly.
- I wouldn't bind enemy logic and and it's UI so closely (`getSprite`). Imagine, how hard would it be for you to refactor your game for text console (not that you should refactor, but it's good mental exercise to check your design).
- If your enemy logic is shared (movement, position), consider either creating a parent enemy (inheritance) or a class for movement (polymorphism).
- Look up "game type object" pattern, it's related to previous points a bit.

Otherwise it seems like a solid base :)

Comment: > I wouldn't bind enemy logic and and it's UI so closely. Suggestions? Can only be class function or outside, but different for each class.

Comment: Imagine part of your "core" code, that handles the game itself (it's movement, etc). And then another component, that handles purely it's rendering (and user input). And your "core" code doesn't know anything about your render code while your render code knows your "core" code.